# DateDiff And Summing Dates Into A Calendar Of Dates

Tags: vba, excel

```
|Start Date |End Date |Diff|
|15-Feb-17  |16-Feb-17| 2  |
|13-Feb-17  |13-Feb-17| 1  |
|13-Feb-17  |14-Feb-17| 2  |
|01-Feb-17  |10-Feb-17| 1  | '(When dates are like this then the difference = 1)
|15-Jan-17  |15-Feb-17| 3  | '(This = Difference between End Date and First date in 'the calendar)
```

In my VBA code below I receive a type mismatch error when trying achieve the above differences. Please assist with this

```
Sub OnRentCounter()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim StartDate() As Variant
    Dim Date1 As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim Days As Single

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Determine last Row in Column A
         lastRow = Sheet1.Range("B999999").End(xlUp).Row
         Date1 = Cells(2, 6).Value
         'Calculate Difference between Start Date And End Date in Days
         StartDate = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
         For i = LBound(StartDate) To UBound(StartDate)
             EndDate = Cells(2, i).Value
             If StartDate(1, i) < Date1 Then
                 Days = DateDiff("D", Date1, EndDate)
                 Days = Days + 1
                 Cells(i + 1, 3) = Days
                 Days = 0
             ElseIf EndDate < Date1 Then
                     Days = DateDiff("D", Date1, Date1)
                     Days = Days + 1
                     Cells(i + 1, 3) = Days
                     Days = 0
             ElseIf Days = DateDiff("D", StartDate, EndDate) Then
                 Days = Days + 1
                 Cells(i + 1, 3) = Days
                 Days = 0
             End If
         Next i
     End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: when does this type mismatch occur. either at value assignment or at the datediff function?

Comment: you have `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` but not all `Range`s and `Cells` underneath are qualified, add the missing dot `.` as a prefix where needed

Comment: It Occurs at: ElseIf Days = DateDiff("D", StartDate, EndDate) Then

Comment: which array element of `StartDate` are you using ? the entire array ? use `StartDate(1, i)`

Comment: Hi Shai, Please give an example as I do not understand.

Comment: @Anthony not sure what you are trying to achieve, what are you trying to do besided calculate the difference in Column C ? anything else ? is there a special calculation here ?

Comment: Once I have completed differences in the dates I Would like to have result where I have two columns:-

Comment: @Anthony what should be the result in the sixth row, "Start Date" is `15-Jan` and  "Finish Date" is `15-Feb` ? is it 32 ?

Comment: Once I have completed differences in the dates I Would like to calculate the number of times 13Sep17 Occurs in the in dates. The same for 14Sep17 and so on for 31 days so that I may graph the the number of vehicles on rent for the next mont. The start dates and end dates are received from vehicles currently on rent and future reservations.

Comment: No the difference between 15Jan17 and 15Feb17 should be 3. That is the difference between the start date of my calendar 13Feb17 and the EndDate 15Feb17

Answer (score 0):

You were using `DateDiff("D", StartDate, EndDate)` but `StartDate` is a Variant,

it should be : `DateDiff("d", StartDate(i, 1), EndDate)`

```
Sub OnRentCounter()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim StartDate() As Variant
    Dim Date1 As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim Days As Single

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Determine last Row in Column A
         LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         Date1 = .Cells(2, 6).Value
         'Calculate Difference between Start Date And End Date in Days
         StartDate = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value
         For i = LBound(StartDate, 1) To UBound(StartDate, 1)
             EndDate = .Cells(2, i).Value

             Debug.Print Format(StartDate(i, 1),"dd-MMM-yy")
             Debug.Print Format(EndDate,"dd-MMM-yy")
             Debug.Print Format(Date1,"dd-MMM-yy")


             If StartDate(i, 1) < Date1 Then
                 Days = DateDiff("d", Date1, EndDate)
             ElseIf EndDate < Date1 Then
                 Days = DateDiff("d", Date1, Date1)
             ElseIf Days = DateDiff("d", StartDate(i, 1), EndDate) Then

             End If
             .Cells(i + 1, 3) = Days + 1
             Days = 0
         Next i
     End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi R3uk Thanks for the help but running the above code I now receive a Type Mismatch here: StartDate = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

Comment: @Anthony : My bad, I didn't spot that `.Value` was missing, try the edit! ;)

Comment: Hi R3uK Appreciate your time. Running the above code I receive subscript out of range at: If StartDate(1, I) < Date1 Then

Comment: @Anthony : My bad again!^^ it suposed to be `StartDate(i, 1)` not `StartDate(1, i)`. I've edited the code to reflect it! ;)

Comment: Hi R3uK, Thanks for help. The code now runs through but returns 1 for all the DateDiff. I will have to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Anthony : i've edited the code, and add a something to display in immediate window (press Ctrl+G to toggle it) the dates you are loading (you can comment thoses lines of `Debug.Print ...` once you fixed your code). I also took the common lines out of the `If`s and there is nothing in the last case, I'll let you figure it out. Place a break point on each line of the `If`s to see how the calculation go! ;)